# Sending current loggedIn user to react front end by node js

Tags: json, reactjs, api, express, frontend

I am trying to send the current loggedIn user to react front end.Below is my middleware function
    I am just not able to get any response in my postman if with the following code.Any help would be muchly appreciated.Thanks

```
    exports.isLoggedIn = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

      if ( req.cookies.jwt){

      // 2) Verification token
      const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      // 3) Check if user still exists
      const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
      if (!currentUser) {
        return next();
      }

      // 4) Check if user changed password after the token was issued
      if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
        return next();
      }

      // Theres is a logged User
       req.user = currentUser
       if(req.user){

       res.status(200).json({
           data: //how to extract user from req.user here
         })
      }
}


      next();

});
```

The error I get is

```
    {
    "status": "error",
    "error": {
        "stringValue": "\"logged-in\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "logged-in",
        "path": "_id",
        "reason": {},
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error"
    },
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"logged-in\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Tour\"",
    "stack": "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"logged-in\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Tour\"\n    at model.Query.exec (F:\\LoginSystem\\api\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:4351:21)\n    at model.Query.Query.then (F:\\LoginSystem\\api\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:4443:15)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please put your error message in a code block like you did with the rest of the code.

Comment: Hi, pavel I have just edited the errors code.do you think you can help me?